# Long screencast software

Tags: screen-recording

I would like to record my screen for a long time (about 2 hours). With QuickTime, that I use currently, I've got FPS problems when the video reaches 30 minutes of recording.

Do you know a software (Windows or Mac) that is well optimized (no FPS drops with the time) and that splits files when they reach the software limit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this I would recommend using [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/). To make open broadcaster software record at 60 fps it requires a bit of tweaking but once you get it working install the plugin live split and you should be able to set up live split to split videos once they get long enough.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to use [ActivePresenter](https://atomisystems.com/activepresenter/free-edition/) which is developed by Atomi systems. With free edition you totally find it easy to record without time limitation and maintain the high quality in the output.

See below:

[image]

Comment: What is your affiliation with this product?

Comment: I'm a coder ofr ActivePresenter. I just want to recommend the solutions for the asker.

Comment: As you seem to post this product everywhere, and it's the only thing you do, without disclosing your affiliation we must consider this spam. Apart from that, your answer doesn't even cover how the product fits the requirements, see [our guide on what an answer should contain](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185).